# how to add image logo in nav-bar bootstrap 5?

Tags: image, navbar, bootstrap-5

i want to add image logo in nav-bar using bootstrap 5

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="demo-logo.png"  alt="logo" >demo-logo
          </a>
i'm using this code by many way but, it didn't working
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
 <div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24">
 </a>
</div>
</nav>
```

[Check This](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)

Comment: it's also not working

Comment: Please explain your code. Also do make sure that you explain how the given link helps with the problem.